# find() blogs by category in mongoose not working with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making a blog application with mongodb database using mongoose framework, nodeJs with express and angular on front. Now I'm trying to create a component where all the blog categories from a category schema are fetched and then on clicking them all the blogs on blog schema having that categoryId on their category field should come up. When checking on db as db.blogs.find({'categoryId': 'TRxtZfez'}) all blogs having this particular categoryId are showing up nicely. But while checking on node controller function result.categoryId is fetching undefined

Node Function:

```
app.get(baseUrl+'view/by/category/:categoryId', (req, res) => {
    BlogModel.find({ 'categoryId': req.params.categoryId }, (err, result) => {    
        if (err) {console.log(err)
            let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'Failed to find category details', 500, null)
            res.send(apiResponse)
        } else if (result == undefined || result == null || result == '') {
            console.log('No Blog Found')
            let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'No such category Found', 404, null)
            res.send(apiResponse)
        } else { let apiResponse = response.generate(false, 'All Blogs with category :: found Successfully', 200, result)
            console.log('BBB'+result.categoryId)  //getting undefined
            res.send(apiResponse)}})})
```

How my blog database looks:

```
    {
        "error": false,
        "message": "All Blogs found Successfully",
        "status": 200,
        "data": [
            {
                "title": "MongoDB",
                "description": "MongoDB is a cross-platform document-oriented database program.",
                "imagePath": "uploads\\1581692172205slider2.png",
                "blogId": "K0llE03j",
                "categoryName": "Technology",
                "categoryId": "TRxtZfez"
            },
            {
                "title": "NodeJs",
                "imagePath": "uploads\\1581692310094shutterstock_339911378-350x350[1].jpg",
                "blogId": "zHi_CUpN",
                "categoryName": "Technology",
                "categoryId": "TRxtZfez"
            },
            {
                "title": "Angular",
                "description": "Angular is a platform for building mobile and desktop web applications.",
                "imagePath": "uploads\\1581692361330mp,550x550,gloss,ffffff,t.3u1[1].jpg",
                "blogId": "ft4w9LVY",
                "categoryName": "Technology",
                "categoryId": "TRxtZfez"
            }
```

Category Database:

```
            "categoryName": "Sports",
            "categoryId": "rtBg1LCZ"
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Movies",
            "categoryId": "zihrNEOP"
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Technology",
            "categoryId": "TRxtZfez"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the result then to access categoryId, you should do:

```
result.data[0].categoryId 
//this will give you first object in the array.
```

Comment: its returning Cannot read property '0' of undefined if I pass result.data[0].categoryId to access categoryId

Comment: Just print result.data to console and see you are getting json object or an json array, if you are getting json object  try result.data.categoryId